# QuarkXpress shortcut for adding custom pagination

Tags: page-layout, book, shortcuts, quarkxpress

I'm creating a booklet in QuarkXpress and I have it set up for automatic pagination, but on some of the pages I want to make my own pagination (move to next column or next page).

I used to be able to use the shortcut of <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> and it would do this. Now this doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way without having to put in a number of returns or shortening my text box?

Answer (score 2):

Quark have support documents / manuals on their website for download, e.g. shortcut lists, which you might want to make use of, especially if you last worked with versions before 8.0: http://quark.com/Support/Documentation/QuarkXPress/

What you seem to look for is how to insert the **New Column** or **New Text Box** special character to let subsequent text continue in the next column (or next text box, if no next column exists): Press the <kbd>⌅</kbd> (Enter) key on the key pad, or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌅</kbd> (Shift+Enter) to force it to the next text box.

If you have no 'pro' keyboard and no separate Enter key, you will need to press the <kbd>fn</kbd> key additionally to access this secondary key function on the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you -- I was able to use the fn key and return and that worked

Comment: @RoseMary If that answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted!